# Specify extra attributes when adding to a collection

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, marionette

We have a backbone/marionette app at work and a colleague and I are wondering what the best way is to do this. Here's simplified example of what we wish to do.

You have a list of staff to show on your front-end, the fields you show are:

- employeeReference
- firstName
- lastName

However the form on the **same** page that is used to create a person also requires

- dateOfBirth

(I have heavily simplified this example - the dateOfBirth in our code is actually several select elements, and we would rather not have to ignore parts of a returned model.)

What is the best way of dealing with this? Ideally we want to pass 4 attributes in via REST(POST) in this example, but the returned model should only have 3 attributes.

I've Googled, but most examples are really simple and deal with the same attributes being sent in and out. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about A.)The data you have(the object model) and B.)The view model.

An exclude map is extra logic you dont need, you can create another model and inherit the defaults and extend them or probably create just another view model which contains the same and extra members you need.

So what is missing is actually another model that is the representation of data(view model) which includes/does not the date of birth/other data.

you can then alter the regular model with the data from the view and save it:

```
reulgarModel.set(_.omit(viewModel.toJSON(),"dateOfBirth"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the parse function of your model to do that:

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   parse: function(response, options){
      delete response.dateOfBirth;
      return response;
   }
});
```

Be aware that this will alter the response object, you might be better of cloning it into a new object or just iterate over the properties and build an exclude map somewhere - you might use the options for that.

Answer (score 0):

Just to continue on from @Alexanders answer, but you can create a new instance of a model within the parse function of a collection and return only the bit of the JSON needed for the collection. Here's an example:

```
parse: function(response) {

  if(response.data.dateOfBirth){
    //Create a new model to hold the date of birth selects
    var dobSelect = new DateOfBirthSelects();

    dobSelect.set("days", response.data.dateOfBirth.days);
    dobSelect.set("months", response.data.dateOfBirth.months);
    dobSelect.set("years", response.data.dateOfBirth.years);

  };



  // Return the employee data to create the collection
  return response.data.employees;
```

The JSON referenced would look like the following:

```
...
data:{
"employees":[
{
"employeeReference": 123
"firstName": "John"
"lastName": "Smith"
},
{
"employeeReference": 124
"firstName": "Jean"
"lastName": "Smith"
}
],
"dateOfBirth":{
"days":["01","02","03"...],
"months":["01","02","03"...],
"years":["1991","1992","1993"...],
}

}
...
```